# Right and left hand positions locked initially

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I recently upgraded to unity 2022 and also upgraded oculus integration to the latest version.

Now when I use hand tracking the first 20/30 seconds the right and left anchors of the hands, in TrakingSpace, remain stationary, both in position and in rotation but the fingers work...

[image]

Has anyone had this problem before and know how to fix it?